# Creating an empty list, adding points to it in a function, but error when trying to call it back

Tags: python

I am trying to use a list that I created in a previous function. The list is a set of times (each second is a point) and I need to add points every 1/20th of a second. The list of times was created in a previous function, but when I try to call back the list to np.linspace it, I get a typeerror code saying the global name list1 was not defined.

I've already tried renaming the list to something different like time = [], but this does not help. I've also defined the empty list in the function and outside of the function.

```
def time_finder():
    v = 0
    u = 0
    list1 = []
    while v < 286:
        v = v + 1
        u = u + 1
        z = mce_data[0]
        y = [a for b in z for a in b]
        x = (y)[u]
        w = np.array(x)[0]
        x.tolist()
        list1.append(w)
    return (list1)
    #print(list1)
time_finder()

#adds 1/20th second marks
def twentieth_second():
    u = 0
    while u < 286:
        v = 1
        timea = list1[u]
        timeb = list1[v]
        np.linspace(timea, timeb, parts+19)
        u = u + 1
        v = v + 1
    print list1
twentieth_second()
```

The error that I get is NameError: global name 'list1' is not defined. This error changes depending on the troubleshooting that I do. Sometimes I get a call back error and other times I get an index is out of range error. I'm expecting to get a new list printed with the 1/20 second intervals included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign the results of the first function to a variable:

```
list1 = time_finder()
```

It may even help to move that line into `twentieth_second`

Also your return in the `time_finder` is wrong. Remove the `()` around `list1`

```
#return (list1)
return list1
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I also realized that I need to change the syntax of the np.linspace but I was able to figure that out.

Comment: "It may even help to move that line into `twentieth_second`." Alternatively, `twentieth_second` should take `list1` as an argument.